# How to allow stripe webhook through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, stripe-payments, webhooks

Stripe webhook returning a 301 error. Seems the webhook is having issues with my .htaccess rules. I am wondering if anyone has come up with the right recipe yet.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(?:GET|POST)\ /.*\.php\ HTTP.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite extensionless ".php" URLs
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(activate)/([a-f0-9]+)$ $1.php/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(reset)/([a-f0-9]+)$ $1.php/$2 [L]

# Stripe Webhook IPs via https://stripe.com/docs/ips#webhook-notifications
Order allow,deny
Allow from 3.18.12.63
Allow from 3.130.192.231
Allow from 13.235.14.237
Allow from 13.235.122.149
Allow from 18.211.135.69
Allow from 35.154.171.200
Allow from 52.15.183.38
Allow from 54.88.130.119
Allow from 54.88.130.237
Allow from 54.187.174.169
Allow from 54.187.205.235
Allow from 54.187.216.72
satisfy any
```

Comment: The issue might be with how you have the redirect rule set up for the `example.com` and `www.example.com` domains. Have you tried disabling the redirect rules to see if that changes things?

Comment: What URL(s) is Stripe requesting? A 301 would only be returned (from `.htaccess` at least) if Stripe is requesting a non-canonical URL (eg. www or HTTP or any URL that ends in `.php`). (Nitpick, but a 301 is not an "error".) If you are unable to change the "Stripe URL(s)" then maybe include exception(s) for these URLs. Then again, are you sure that the 301 is triggered by `.htaccess` and not your application?

Comment: Yes MrWhite that was it. I overlooked that. webhook was example.com/webhook.php when actually because of my rewrite rules i just needed example.com/webhook.  Thanks for catching that.